# Angularjs ng-repeat of string variable with special characters

Tags: angularjs, character, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing an ng-repeat of an array with strings in it.  The problem is some of the strings have special characters like "degrees" and fractional numbers.  The output for the first item in the array below is "Oven 350&#176"....instead of "Oven 350*".

```js
directions = [
    "Oven 350&#176;",
    "Cook potatoes in boiling salted water until done",
    "The next day grate potatoes coarsely",
    "Mix with remaining ingredients",
    "Place in shallow 1.5 or 2 quart baking dish and bake about 35 minutes"
   ];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in directions"></li>
</ul
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the special characters to work you need to use ngBindHtml [Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

In order to use ngBindHtml you need to include angular-sanitize.min.js and include ngSanitize in your modules dependencies

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in directions">
      <span ng-bind-html='item'></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.directions = [
                "Oven 350&#176;",
                "Cook potatoes in boiling salted water until done",
                "The next day grate potatoes coarsely",
                "Mix with remaining ingredients",
                "Place in shallow 1.5 or 2 quart baking dish and bake about 35 minutes"
            ];
}
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8u7tkrjw/)